# Elastic Beanstalk timeout when uploading large image to s3

Tags: file, ruby-on-rails-4, upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I've got a problem when uploading large images to amazon s3. I'm using Rails 4 with carrierwave gem. I've see many similar posts here on stackoverflow that people answered to use carrierwave_direct. My problem is that I can't put one form into another, and need to send all the data together, including the image upload. The only option I see, is to limit file size, but I'm avoiding. Is there any way to increase this timeout on the server or any configuration file inside rails project?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on your setup? Why do you need to put one form into another? The general idea is that the processing should be done as a background process, not in the request handler. It would be helpful if you post the code of your form

Comment: Most web servers have a config option for max file size upload. In nginx it looks like client_max_body_size 500M;

Comment: You could compress the image before sending, and then whenever you need to access it uncompress again.

Comment: What is timing out?  if it's your app, then how about pushing into a thread.  I like to use the spawnling gem to toss the upload into it and then return to the user interface.  I run a javascript check on status to poll whether the upload is done, (i use the DB record that references the file to indicate when it is done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My timeout was in the Javascript, was timing out the requests.